# Bash looping logic behind convention

Tags: bash

I'm a bit new to Bash programming, but I was curious during my learning so I wanted to ask what is the logic (or reason) behind as to why:

```
#/bin/sh
ITERS="1 2 3 4"
for i in $ITERS;
do
    echo hi
done
```

`echo`s hi 4 times, while

```
#/bin/sh
for i in "1 2 3 4";
do
    echo hi
done
```

Only `echo`s it once? And how can I achieve the above behaviour without declaring a variable?

Comment: Are you looking for, simply, `for i in 1 2 3 4`?

Comment: yes, however, why can't the string also work?

Comment: Because then you are looping over the single, quoted string, which is one value.

Comment: Incidentally, your question is tagged `bash`, but your examples indicate `/bin/sh`.  They are different shells, with different features; even when `/bin/sh` is a symlink to Bash, it disables (some) Bash-only features.

Comment: @tripleee is right, look at the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: It doesn't actually matter here, though; Bash is perfectly backward-compatible, and there are no Bash features in this script.

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this question as a duplicate. If the linked question answers your concerns, I'll just go ahead and do that. If not, please [edit] your question to clarify what sort of background you require. Quoting is a sticky topic but writing another tutorial seems excessive, as there are tons of them already.